# Hazelcast Failover in WAN Replication

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I have a Hazelcast WAN Setup with three WAN - London, NY and Australia

where,

London has 1.1.1.1 and 1.1.1.2

NY has 1.1.1.3 and 1.1.1.4

Australia has 1.1.1.5 and 1.1.1.6

1) It is working as expected (i.e) Client pointing to London, reads the data only from London cluster. Client pointing to NY, reads the data only from NY cluster. Client pointing to Australia, reads the data only from Australia. Everything is working fine.

2) But when London cluster goes down, the client in London is not pointing to other cluster. I know this is How it works? Its all fine. But Is there a way to tweak the functionality like pointing to other clusters in case of current cluster failure.

NOTE : Am using group config in WAN Configuration.

It would be Great, If somebody get backs.

Thanks,
Harry

Answer (score 1):

There is no build in way, you would have to build something like this yourself by automatically connecting to the second cluster when the first one goes down.